# Change of Residence 1040-X

Tags: united-states, taxes, foreign-income

I work for an American company but live and pay taxes abroad. I filed my 2021 taxes (w-2 employee) without taking advantage of the foreign income deduction (ex. I put a US mailing address as my physical address).

Can I amend my taxes to use the deduction? If so how?

I used the deduction in 2020, and want to use it in 2022. I definitely qualify. I just made some errors in the 2021 filing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can most definitely amend your tax return to make a FEIE election. See [the IRS site on this](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/choosing-the-foreign-earned-income-exclusion):

> Your initial choice of the exclusion(s) on Form 2555, Foreign Earned Income, generally must be made with:
>
> - a timely filed return (including any extensions),
> - **a return amending a timely filed return**, or
> - a late-filed return filed within 1 year from the original due date of the return (determined without regard to any extensions).